# Nullpointerexception while setting a bean

Tags: java, struts2, nullpointerexception, action, javabeans

I have an action URL after clicking a hyper link like so

```
/SocialStupendous/GetProfile.action?slno=3&slno=3
```

In my `execute` method of `ActionClass` I have the following code

```
public String execute() {
  int urislno=Integer.parseInt(getServletRequest().getParameter("slno"));
  System.out.println(urislno);
  bean.setUslno(urislno);       
}
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` when I am performing `bean.setuslno(urislno)`. Even though `urislno` is printed properly as `3`.

**`ProfileBean` class:**

```
public class ProfileBean {

  private int uslno;

  public int getUslno() {
    return uslno;
  }

  public void setUslno(int uslno) {
    this.uslno = uslno;
  }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you accessing the parameter directly from the request in the first place? With regards to the NPE, shouldn't it be obvious what's wrong after seeing what's null?

Comment: i want to get hold of those users whomsoever has clicked the url saying getprofile.action .The only way to catch the user was via his/hers slno. Hence i wanted to test if i am able to access the parameters from url which changes corresponding to users

Comment: There is no need to access the request directly, use av action property.

Comment: Can you kindly brief me up on the av action ,  i dont know this as am new to struts

Comment: "An action property", it was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bean` is not initialized. You should initialize it somehow in the action

```
private ProfileBean bean = new ProfileBean(); 
//and add getter ans setter
```

the better approach, however is let the container to do it for you. You just need to create a bean configuration in the `struts.xml`

```
<bean class="com.yourpackagename.ProfileBean" scope="default"/>
```

then you would have

```
private ProfileBean bean;

@Inject
public void setProfileBean(ProfileBean bean) {
  this.bean = bean;
}
```

and you don't need to parse request for parameters, this is already done by the `params` interceptor which is a part of `defaultStack` that your action should run. You should create properties in your action to hold parameter values.

```
private Integer slno;

public Integer getSlno() {
    return slno;
}

public void setSlno(Integer uslno) {
    this.slno = slno;
}
```

and the action will look like

```
public String execute() {

   if (slno != null) {
     System.out.println(slno)
     bean.setUslno(slno);
   }

   ......
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: = I am new to this kindly tell me how to answer it as accepted