# JSON object is not setting variable in Struts2 Action

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I'm really struggling with complex json objects as the following:

```
var data= {service:{
                    client:{idClient: idClient},
                    pet:{idPet: idPet},
                    employee:{idEmployee: idEmployee},
                    conclusion: ''+conclusion}};
```

I'm sending it through this :

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'registerService.action',
            type:'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            succes: function(data){
                //do something
            }
    });
```

And a exception is triggered: java.lang.NullPointerException, which means that the variable service in the action hasn't been instantiated.

```
public class SomeAction extends ActionSupport{
private Service service; //getter y setter

public String registerService(){
    Integer cod= (getServiceService().registerService(service));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And the Service class looks like this one

```
public class Service {
//everything with its respective setter a getter
private Client client;
private Pet pet;
private Employee employee;
private String conclusion;

public Service(){
  client = new Client();
  pet = new Pet();
  employee= new Employee();
}

}
```

Also, each id of the different objects are Integer.

I hope to get a help, please
thanks in advance

---

SOLUTION

After the instatiation of the object service, its attributes were null and that was because I didn't include in struts.xml and the action mapping the respective interceptor as the following

struts.xml

```
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
</interceptors>
```

action mapping

```
<action name="registerService" class="servicioActionSpring"  method="registerService">
        <interceptor-ref name="json"/>
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right the properties should be initialized.

```
private Service service = new Service(); //getter y setter
```

or you can do it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488971/573032) way using internal DI mechanism. If you are using other DI frameworks you should use corresponding plugins.

Because you are sending JSON to the action make sure you have used `json` interceptor in the action config.

Comment: Really? I though that Struts 2 was in charge of the object instantiation through the setter method

Comment: setter is used to set a value to the object property, not the object instantiation.

Comment: so, why if I have for instance: `private String someName;` and I send a key/value pair that matches with it, the variable is initializated ? through its setter method I think

Comment: Because the object is passed as a parameter to the method. In your case a getter is used for the `service` property.

Comment: definitely, this works the service is instantiated now, but...what is happening if the objects as client, pet, employee and even the conclusion attribute  are not initialized although they have its getter and setters

Comment: Actually `json` interceptor should populate your objects, which you should include in the action config.