# Converting Action in Struts 1 to Struts 2 equivalent

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts-1, model-driven

I am trying to migrate an application from Struts 1 to Struts 2. In the migration process, I am facing the following issues:

1. There is a `Servlet` which extends `ActionServlet` of Struts1. There are many overriden methods where by `super` is being called like `process()`, I would like to know its equivalent to convert to Struts2. As I am not getting its equivalent in `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.
2. I have converted all the form beans into `ModelDriven` beans and all the `Action`s to a class extending `ActionSupport`. Also made entry in `struts.xml` for it.

Please provide your silutions on the above two issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process` is running before the action executes. The purpose of overriding the framework classes is to change/extend the functionality. Most of modifications are related to the old framework and could be dropped. If you need to use some code that cannot be replaced in Struts2 then you should write a custom interceptor. This is a normal way to change/extend the functionality in Struts2 instead of classes overrides.

You can read more about [interceptors](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors.html) on the Struts docs site.

You should be fine with your architecture, but `ModelDriven` could be replaced with injecting bean(s) into controller. See [Nullpointerexception while setting a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488971/573032).

Sometimes the scope of the bean is important, for example Struts1 uses a session scope by default. You can inject a `sessionMap` with the interceptor ant keep your objects in session if you need them or try to implement a session scoped bean like I did in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032) question.

Comment: I am facing same situation, there is a filter which is getting authentication before landing to home page of struts 1 application and  that filter also mapped with a Servlet having some initialization code and setting session / request params later used by action(s).
How I can migrate this code to Struts2. Please help

Comment: @HusMukh If you have a question better ask it by the [Ask question] button above. Don't comment on the posts that is not related to its content. You might want to upvote a question and answer if it helped you?